# Getting the Maximum values from the different columns in a dataframe of R

Tags: r, data-science

I have a dataframe as below:

```
H   A   B   C   D
------------------
X   1   10  2   11
Y   2   15  8   14
Z   NA  23  NA  16
W   5   67  5   NA
X   4   1   6   2
Y   1   3   2   9
Z   2   NA  9   17
```

Can you please tell me the R command which gives me corresponding H value for max value of A, max value of B, max Value of C and max value of D and stores the data in a vector.

Maximum value in col A is 5, Max value in col B is 67, Max value in col C is 9 and Max value in D is 17.

My new vector should have H references as 'W','W','Z','Z'

Thanks

Comment: This is what  I'm looking for.. Thank you very much..

Comment: Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: You can try `apply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data$H[sapply(data[,-1],which.max)]
```

Comment: I reckon you've got the right idea. You can shorten it a bit though - `dat$H[sapply(dat[-1], which.max)]`

Comment: which.max only takes one argument. And in a vector which contain NA which.max will return NA , to use it, we still have to write a function:            
   dat$H[sapply(dat[-1],function(x)  which.max(na.omit(x)))]

Comment: Nope, `which.max(c(NA,1,NA,3,4,5))` returns `6`, for the index of the value `5`. As per `?which.max` - "*Missing and ‘NaN’ values are discarded.*"

Comment: And how do you highlight the code in the comment section?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
m1 <- t(df1[-1])
df1[,1][max.col(replace(m1, is.na(m1), 0), "first")]
#[1] "W" "W" "Z" "Z"
```

Comment: @user2071685 Here you go , an nice alternate solution!+1

Comment: This feels a bit convoluted to me. You're transposing a column-based data.frame, in the process converting it to a matrix, to then look across rows as a proxy for a column. Why not just look in the columns to start with? Unless of course it's markedly faster (I doubt it, but you never know).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `reshape` and `dplyr`

```
DF=melt(df)
DF=DF%>%group_by(variable)%>%slice(which.max(value))
DF
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   variable [4]
      H variable value
  <chr>   <fctr> <int>
1     W        A     5
2     W        B    67
3     Z        C     9
4     Z        D    17
```

If you need the `vector`, just need `DF$H`

```
[1] "W" "W" "Z" "Z"
```